# Cumulative Sum not calculating correctly when segmented by month

Tags: powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum

I'm working with a dataset in Power BI which contains a table entitled "Transactions" which column showing revenue collected and the date of the transaction. Ultimately, we want to find the cumulative running total of those transactions.

| `Transaction Date` | `Amount` |
| --- | --- |
| `1/5/2023` | `$ 1,000` |
| `1/14/2023` | `$ 450` |
| `2/5/2023` | `$ (500)` |
| `2/22/2023` | `$ 1,453` |
| `2/22/2023` | `$ 220` |
| `5/1/2023` | `$ (2,000)` |
| `11/1/2023` | `$ 2,500` |

A relationship exists between this table and a table entitled "Calendar Table" which appears as follows:

| `Date` | `Year` | `Month` | `Start of Month` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `1/1/2023` | `2023` | `Sunday, January 1, 2023` | `January 2023` |
| `1/2/2023` | `2023` | `Monday, January 2, 2023` | `January 2023` |
| `1/3/2023` | `2023` | `Tuesday, January 3, 2023` | `January 2023` |

The table maintains this format for all 365 days of 2023.
The two tables have a relationship using the 'Transaction Date' column and the 'Date' column respectively.

What we are trying to accomplish is to create a Matrix chart which will display the cumulative total of all Amount transactions at the end of each Month. Currently, the Matrix table has 'Month' (from the Calendar Table) as the columns and 'Cumulative Amount' (DAX formula) as the Values.

So we would want to see something like this:

| `Thursday, January 5, 2023` | `Saturday, January 14, 2023` | `Friday, February 5, 2023` | `Wednesday, February 22, 2023` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `$ 1,000` | `$ 1,450` | `$ 950` | `$ 2,403` |

The DAX measure I am using for the Cumulative Amount is as follows:

`Cumulative Amount =`
`CALCULATE( 'Transactions'[Amount],`
`FILTER(ALL('Transactions'[Transaction Date] ),`
`'Transactions'[Transaction Date] <= MAX(''Transactions'[Transaction Date]) ) )`

When I apply this DAX in the values of the Matrix, I get the following result:

| `Thursday, January 5, 2023` | `Saturday, January 14, 2023` | `Friday, February 5, 2023` | `Wednesday, February 22, 2023` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `$ 1,000` | `$ 450` | `$ (500)` | `$ 1,673` |

Question: How can I get my DAX measure to calculate the cumulative total like we want? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is working with this DAX formula:

```
 Cumulative Amount = 
    CALCULATE(Sum( 'Transactions'[Amount]),
    FILTER(ALL('Transactions'[Transaction Date] ),
    'Transactions'[Transaction Date] <= MAX('Transactions'[Transaction Date]) ) )
```

Also, make sure both the date columns used in the data relationship are data type "Date" and not "DateTime".

[image]